# Lucene Spatial Strategy

Tags: lucene, geospatial, spatial

I have the following use case:

I want to be able to search my lucene documents within a certain circle of radius x kms from the given user lat long.

I also want to sort the documents by distance.

I also need the distnace values later on to display to user.

Which spatial strategy would be best for me without indexing anything extra and considering performance.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirements, I think the best choice could be the `PointVectorStrategy`, which is the simplest one and also satisfy your conditions:

> Simple SpatialStrategy which represents Points in two numeric fields.
>   The Strategy's best feature is decent distance sort.
>
> Characteristics:
>
> - Only indexes points; just one per field value.
> - Can query by a rectangle or circle.
> - SpatialOperation.Intersects and SpatialOperation.IsWithin is supported.
> - Requires DocValues for SpatialStrategy.makeDistanceValueSource(org.locationtech.spatial4j.shape.Point)
>     and for searching with a Circle.

Yes, it will require you to have DocValues indexed, but if I understand correctly, none of the spatial strategies will be provide needed functionality for free.